# Node RESTAPI framework for existing MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I am looking for node js REST Api for an application which already has MySql DB.

I do not want to change the DB now as it has been using already for web application.

Please suggest.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go ahead and proceed with the MySql DB. So what's the problem in that??

Comment: If you are looking for frameworks all express, sails, and loopback support rest apis and mysql/oracle/mongodb. what is the actual goal you are trying to reach?

Comment: You can use this project on github--https://github.com/mataprasad/node-mssql/blob/master/mysql.js

Comment: I have huge data already on my DB. I do not want to change my db schema for the restapi now. When I looked in to loopback it has pretty poor support or document for connecting existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

This example you can use any Boilerplate which has already build over node with Mysql comibination .

As same kind of Boilerplate i build for my Requirement you can use that ,link is [here](https://github.com/yug95/node-mysql)